# Find node from known starting point in totally dynamic webpage using c# and XPath?

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to write automated smoketest for an internal website. The problem is the website is almost primarily dynamically generated. So any kind of unique identifier like ID is a combination of known string prefix and ends with a radomized number.

I also can NOT depend on the order, so using things like div[2] or span[25] will not be reliable, UNLESS there is some way to grab the count of the span/div/input based on where I am currently located in the DOM by the KNOWN TEXT VALUE.

For example I can find the known text value. If I can somehow programatically determine that the span for this known text value is 55 , and I know that it is nested 2 deep from the other element I am looking for, then I could do something like "//span[55 - 2]/input".

The best I can do is navigate the DOM to some KNOWN text value, and work up OR down from there.

Given that, in the example below, how would I navigate to the INPUT element, when starting from the KNOWN TEXT VALUE???

```html
<span id="RandomlyGenerated35673">
 <span id="RandomlyGeneratedNum58532">
  <span id="RandomlyGenerated78539">
   <span/>
   <span/>
   <span id="RandomlyGenerated78539">KNOWN TEXT VALUE</span>
  </span>
 </span>
 <input class="GENERIC-NON-UNIQUE" type="button" value="GENERIC-NON-UNIQUE"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`following` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following):

```
//span[. = 'KNOWN TEXT VALUE']/following::input[@type = 'button']
```

Comment: Thanks this gets me one step further! Unfortunately now it is complaining about the element not being visible when I try and programatically "Click" on it. I checked the "Displayed" property of element, and it is false. I checked the "Enabled" property and it is true. <input class="dijitOffScreen" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" value=""/>

Comment: @guht that sounds like a different problem, please see if it makes sense to create a new question if you have difficulties. Thanks.